# How can I get messages beta to start in "hidden mode"

Tags: messages

I have installed the beta of messages. I understand the software is beta and I have searched all the Apple messages forums and Google around for a solution but could not find one.

I have set messages to launch upon startup via the icon in the dock as follows:

[image]

However when I log into OS X Lion 10.7.3 the primary new message window pops up:

[image]

This has the effect of having the messages icon in my dock active in addition to having a new message windows pop up.

My desire is to have messages start up without having a new message windows open upon login. Is there an obvious way to accomplish this? I have tried using minimize scripts which minimize the new message window but still results in having two icons active in my dock as follows:

[image]

I have additionally made sure that the "*Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps*" setting under general preferences is not on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an AppleScript to do that for you.

1. Open AppleScript Editor
2. Type/paste this in:

```
    tell application "iChat"
        set minimized of window 1 to true
    end tell
```

```
launch "iChat"
tell application "iChat"
    close window 1
end tell
```

1. Save as an application somewhere
2. Open System Preferences > User/Accounts > Login Items
3. Click Add, navigate to application, add and enable

Comment: Wouldn't it be `tell application "Messages"`? Or is the name still "iChat"?

Comment: The app is still called iChat for some reason? Probably will be changed once the software comes out of beta. @Vidur Murali, I tried your solution and it does what you indicate but it turns out my question was not clear enough as to what I was trying to accomplish. I have clarified the question with additional screen shots and information.

Comment: @daviesgeek The beta Messages is still called "iChat". It took me a second to figure out too when I couldn't find the .app file.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure if it actually *was* changed to "Messages" or not.

Comment: @Mort I understand what you're trying to do better. The reason I didn't notice this is because I have my minimize preferences set to 'Minimize into icon' or something similar (I don't remember what the exact preference name is).

So the script right now simulates clicking of the orange '-' button on the window. The solution would be to simulate clicking of the red 'x' button.

Going to google around and be back in a bit with an edit.

Comment: @VidurMurali Your script does indeed work but I think I may be having a timing issue as to when the script runs. It seem as though if the script runs prior to the iChat new message window being fully initialized I get an error as follows: **"Can't get window 1 of application iChat. Invalid index."**

Comment: @Mort This would be the simplest fix: Trust the script to open Messages for you. That way the close window command only executes once the app is done launching. This seems to work for me. Let me know what you think. It happens pretty instantaneously too, I can't even see the window before it's gone.

Comment: @ VidurMurali That may be doable but how would I alter said script to accommodate.